# Is the Android desktop screen (on any version) a Dalvik executable?

Tags: home-screen, dalvik

I know that all Android apps, as far as I know, are compiled to Java bytecode, turned into dex code (for the [Dalvik Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)), and then executed with respect to whatever [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is compatible between the VM and its linking/exposure.

However, after booting Android, I always wondered if the desktop itself was also a Dalvik executable, or if it's not running on the virtual machine as all other apps do?

What do I mean by "desktop"? I mean the home screen:

[image]

Could anyone clarify this/does anyone know this? Not the widgets, backgrounds, etc., but the essence of the whole GUI/home screen/desktop. Is it an "app" that runs on Dalvik, like all others supposedly do, or is it a system process/separate process running outside of the virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe as "desktop", and the screenshot shows, is called by different names. Mostly it listens on the names [Launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/launcher/info) and [Homescreen](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/home-screen/info), depending on the aspect referred to. And yes, it's an app that ships with its own `.apk` file, as all its "replacements" (e.g. *Apex Launcher*, *GoLauncher*, or *Holo Launcher* – to name some) do.